# Draw an inclined ellipse in PStricks

Tags: pstricks

I would like to draw an inclined ellipse in PStricks, but seems the angle command does not work here. How can I make my ellipse inclinde?

```
  \psellipse[linestyle=dashed,angle=-30,linecolor=red,dash=3pt 2pt](-2,3)(0.5,0.5)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the `rot` option:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-3)(3,4)
\psellipse[linestyle=dashed, rot=-30,linecolor=red, dash=3pt 2pt](0.5,0.5)(1,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{pstricks}` can be removed because `standalone` with `pstricks` option loads the package automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Using composite transformation just for refreshing elementary school math.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-3)(3,4)
\rput(0.5,0.5){\rput{-30}(0,0){\rput(-0.5,-0.5){\psellipse[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,dash=3pt 2pt](0.5,0.5)(1,3)}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or with `pstricks-add` you could also rotate with `\psrotate(0.5,0.5){-30}{\psellipse(0.5,0.5)(1,3)}`.

Comment: Yours can be simplified as `\rput{-30}(0.5,0.5){\psellipse[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,dash=3pt 2pt](1,3)}`